# Getting Type Expected Error when calling Jquery function from vb.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I am calling Jquery function from code behind using following code. But getting type Expected error near GetType() function.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
  Me,
  GetType(),
  "Close Modal Popup",
  "Closepopup();",
  true
)
```

I am using VB.net as Code Behind.

thanks in advance for Help!

Answer (score 0):

VB has a `GetType` keyword that will return a `Type` object given a data type, e.g.

```
Dim stringType = GetType(String)
```

That's what you are invoking there, but you're not providing a data type so it fails.  Presumably you are actually trying to call the `GetType` method of the current object.  In that case, you need to either escape the identifier so that it is not interpreted as a keyword:

```vb
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
  Me,
  [GetType](),
  "Close Modal Popup",
  "Closepopup();",
  True
)
```

or invoke it on the current instance explicitly:

```vb
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
  Me,
  Me.GetType(),
  "Close Modal Popup",
  "Closepopup();",
  True
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.7.2) has overloads like this:

```
Public Shared Sub RegisterStartupScript(Page, Type, String, String, Boolean)

Public Shared Sub RegisterStartupScript(Control, Type, String, String, Boolean)
```

The error message itself indicates that `GetType()` method requires a type to be set, hence you should setting up that method like example below:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType(), "Close Modal Popup", "Closepopup();", True)
```